# Using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus during getting first order differential equation

Tags: calculus

I am having problem while solving a question below:

[image]

I have looked into solution to understand the process of solving this problem, and encountered a part that I do not understand.
The part I can't get the grasp is:

[image]

I don't understand the bottom part of the explanation where it says "Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to find y'". How does y' becomes x - 4y?

I am taking Calc 2 after taking Calc 1 10 years ago, and it has been rough.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: To find $y'$ : This is just the application of the FTC. Could you clarify what you miss ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the formula you're looking for:

If $$y=\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} f(t)dt$$
Then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f[\psi(x)]\psi'(x)-f[\phi(x)]\phi'(x)$$

So, according to your sum,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=[x-4y(x)]\frac{d}{dx}(x)-[2-4y(2)]\frac{d}{dx}(2)$$
Hence, $$y'=x-4y$$